# iOS- Get button on MKAnnotationView to delete pin

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have created a `MKAnnotationView` and do add a `UIButton` on it. Now I would like that button to remove the pin it is in.

This is how I add the button:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotation = nil;
    if(annotation != myMapView.userLocation) 
    {
        NSString *defaultPinID = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"pin%d",pinCount];
        pinAnnotation = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[myMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinAnnotation == nil )
            pinAnnotation = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];
        pinAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;

    //// ADDING MY BUTTON
        UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pinAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = deleteButton;
    //// ADDING IT'S ACTION
        [deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deletePin) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    pinCount++;
    return pinAnnotation;
}
```

As you can see there, I set the action to call this method:

```
-(void)deletePin
{
    //What to put here...?
}
```

**How can I make that action delete it's button's pin?**

I figured maybe sending the `id` thru or something, but am not sure how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With annotation callout accessory views, do not use your own target/action method.

Instead, use the map view's `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method which will make this job much easier.

Remove the `addTarget` line and your custom method.  Then implement the delegate method instead:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
            calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    [mapView removeAnnotation:view.annotation];
}
```

Also, unrelated, but the way you are setting the re-use identifier is wrong and defeats re-usability by assigning a different id to every annotation.  The following is recommended:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinAnnotationView = nil;
    if (annotation != myMapView.userLocation) 
    {
        NSString *reuseId = @"StandardPin";
        pinAnnotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[myMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
        if ( pinAnnotationView == nil )
        {
            pinAnnotationView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId] autorelease];
            pinAnnotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

            UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            pinAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = deleteButton;
        }
        else
            //update annotation property if view is being re-used...
            pinAnnotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return pinAnnotationView;
}
```

Comment: How can I delete from another viewController?

Comment: @Camus: Please ask a new question with details and code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Get the sender in your callback

```
[deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deletePin:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)deletePin:(id)sender
{
    //What to put here...?
}
```

Then get the MKAnnotation associated with the MKPinAnnotationView, remove it from the MKMapView's annotations and redraw (`[mapView setNeedsDisplay]`)